# One-way async/await calls in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, async-await

I have a legacy WCF service with a number of One-Way operation contracts implemented in the most classic way:

```
    // The interface
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true, AsyncPattern = true)]
    IAsyncResult BeginFinalizePublishing(PageContent pageContent, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState);
    void EndFinalizePublishing(IAsyncResult result);

    // The service
    public IAsyncResult BeginFinalizePublishing(PageContent pageContent, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {...}
```

So everything works fine here, now I need to convert this to c# 5 latest async/await pattern. Pay attention to the one way nature of the operations. My questions:

- I guess I need to remove the `AsyncPattern = true` from the `OperationContract` attribute.
- Replace the `IAsyncResult` return type with the `void` in the interface and `async void` in the class.
- Remove the Begin/End and add the Async postfix for the sake of convenience.

*Now how should I call the one-way operation from the client?*
No usage of async/await on the client-side right for one-way calls?

Is this correct and will result in a true asynchronous processing on the client side.

```
    // The proxy
    public void FinalizePublishingAsync(PageContent pageContent)
    {
        Channel.FinalizePublishingAsync(pageContent);
    }

        // The consumer of the client
        // No way to use await for void methods. 
        IComPublisherFinalizerClient cl = new IComPublisherFinalizerClient();
        cl.FinalizePublishingAsync(content); 
        cl.Close();
```

Answer (score 6):

First off, the client is entirely separate from the server. Either client or server may be synchronous, use `IAsyncResult` (APM) asynchronous code, or use `async` (TAP) asynchronous code.

Secondly, `async` methods on the server side should return `Task`, even for one-way communications. The `async` equivalent of a synchronous method returning `void` is an `async Task` method, not an `async void` method. `async void` is especially dangerous in WCF services since it may violate the `ConcurrencyMode`.

So your server-side steps would look like this:

- Remove `OperationContract.AsyncPattern`.
- Combine the `Begin*`/`End*` method pair into a single `*Async` method which returns `Task`.

Your client side should see `Task`-returning methods on the interface for its proxy, which it should `await`. This does not mean that you're waiting for a response; this `await` enables you to wait for the actual message to be sent (if there are delays) and detect channel communications errors (if you are using a reliable channel).

Comment: Stephen, Thanks for the reply. One-Way calls don't have a reply message and are awaited until the server gets the request - this is why they are marked as a void. But as I know (Juval writes about this) the server actualy does send a short reply msg saying that the client request is queued. The IAsyncResult solves this issue. And you want to say that even though the Operation (marked as a OneWay) returns a Task the caller won't be blocked till the server's reply? Or it will act as a regular OneWay operation blocking till the servers' reply?

Comment: It will act as a regular OneWay operation. So it won't wait for the server method to complete (or be invoked) and it won't report errors from the server.