# Ping replies of a WCF service while busy with long running operations

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I'm developing a client/server application using WPF and WCF.
The server application hosts a WCF service that is in charge to execute clients requests and callback them when something occurs.

The service interface define a duplex callback contract with all `OneWay` operations.

**(simplified) IService**

```
[ServiceContract(CallbackContract = typeof(ISrvServiceCallback))]
public interface ISrvService
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void Ping();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void LongRunningOperation();
}

public interface ISrvServiceCallback
{
    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void PingReply();

    [OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
    void LongRunningOperationStatus(string reply);
}
```

The service needs to mantain some objects that change states according to clients calls. For this reason I decided to have a singleton service.

**(simplified) Service**

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class SrvService : ISrvService
{
    MyObject statusObject;

    public void LongRunningOperation()
    {
        //calling back the client reporting operation status
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISrvServiceCallback>()
        .LongRunningOperationStatus("starting long running application");

        statusObject.elaborateStatus();

        //calling back the client reporting object status
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISrvServiceCallback>()
        .LongRunningOperationStatus("object status: " + statusObject.ToString());
    }

    public void Ping()
    {
        OperationContext.Current.GetCallbackChannel<ISrvServiceCallback>().PingReply();
    }


    public SrvService()
    {
        statusObject= ...statusObject init...
    }

}
```

As you can see I have a **Ping** operation exposed by the service that a client calls (every 5 seconds) to check if the server application is available on the network (each client has a *server connectivity icon* with **red**=server not available, **green**=server not available).

When a client requests a **long running operation**, the server starts working on that operation and can't reply to the ping requests (the client's *server connectivity icon* turns red).

Once the long running operation finishes, the server replies to **all** the requests made by the client and the *server connectivity icon* turns back green).

I would like to find a way to develop the service so the server always replies to the ping requests, also when a long operation is running.

- How can I do it considering that i need to keep
  `InstanceContextMode.Single` to mantain the state of the objects of
  the service?
- Are there other/better ways to ping a WCF service
  availability and visually display the result on the client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a singleton service you're going to need a multi threaded implementation of your server instance to get the desired behavior, at the very least you'll need to run LongRunningOperation on a separate thread.  If this operation is inherently not thread safe, you'll need to guard against multiple concurrent calls to it specifically with a lock or semaphore, etc in the implementation.  This way when a client calls LongRunningOperation(), it executes in a separate thread and is free to respond to ping requests.

There are many ways to implement this. By the way you worded your question the client seems to be making asynchronous calls (as it appears to be making ping requests while waiting for LongRunningOperation to return) - so I'm also going to assume you have some knowledge of asynchronous programming. WCF has some [built in ways of handling concurrency](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731193(v=vs.110).aspx), but most of the documentation does not cover singleton instances so you're going to need to read carefully and focus on that special case.

I've had the most success with the async/await pattern (see [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/endpoint/2010/11/12/simplified-asynchronous-programming-model-in-wcf-with-asyncawait/) and [here](http://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2013/03/asynchronous-operations-in-wcf.html)) - Once this was set up properly I had a very reliable and predictable pattern for long running service calls in a stateful singleton service.

Also, as far as pings are concerned you do point out that you are simply displaying the connectivity status for the user, but if you had plans to use it for control (checking if the service is online before making a call) [there is a lot of discussions here on why you should avoid it.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2867563/1724034)

**EDIT:**  Quick example with async/await

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface ISrvService()
{
    [OperationContract]
    bool Ping(); // doesnt need to be async

    [OperationContract]
    Task<string> LongRunningOperation();
}
```

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]
public class SrvService : ISrvService
{
    MyObject statusObject;

    public async Task LongRunningOperation()
    {
        // lock/semaphore here if needed
        await Task.Run(() => statusObject.elaborateStatus()); // you could impliment elaborateStatus() as an async Task method and call it without Task.Run
        return statusObject.ToString();
    }

    public bool Ping()
    {
        return true;
    }


    public SrvService()
    {
        statusObject= ...statusObject init...
    }

}
```

```
public class SrvClient : ClientBase<ISrvService>
{
    public async Task<string> LongRunningOperation()
    {
        return await base.Channel.LongRunningOperation();
    }

    public async Task<bool> Ping()
    {
        // note that we still call this with an await. In the client we are awaiting the wcf service call
        // this is independent of any async/await that happens on the server
        return await Task.Run(() => base.Channel.Ping());
    }
}
```

Using the client:

```
public class SomeApplicationClass()
{
    SrvClient Client;
    DispatcherTimer PingTimer;

    public SomeClass()
    {
        BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
        EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress(
            "http://...:8000/Service/Address");
        OutpostClient = new OutpostRemoteClient(binding, endpoint);

        // pingTimer setup

    }

    // async voids are scary, make sure you handle exceptions inside this function
    public async void PingTimer_Tick()
    {
        try
        {
            await Client.Ping();
            // ping succeeded, do stuff
        }
        catch // specify exceptions here
        {
            // ping failed, do stuff
        }
    }

    public async Task DoTheLongRunningOperation()
    {
        // set busy variables here etc.
        string response = await Client.LongRunningOperation();
        // handle the response status here
    }
}
```

Also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15386417/1724034) seems relevant.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @plast1k! I have small knowledge of async and I'm actually exploring that field also. 

The clients ping the service using a _DispatcherTimer_ that calls _ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(checkService)_ . _checkService_ calls the _serviceClient.Ping()_.

I will have a look at all the links you posted and see how i can solve my problem.

Will it be possible to have some sample code of your async/await singleton service implementation? Just to have an idea how to call from client and reply from server.

Comment: No problem. I should be able to dig some up later, I'll edit my post if I find it.

Comment: @aDone example added, sorry that took so long!